# Span<T> can not be a nested local variable. Why is this a restriction?

Tags: c#, c#-7.2, system.memory

The following does not compile. Since this is not an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression, why is this a restriction? (Passing text as ref ReadOnlySpan works fine.)

```
    void TestNestedSpan()
    {
        var text = "Some text".AsReadOnlySpan();
        var success = TryParseS();

        bool TryParseS()
        {
            //Compile Error CS8175 Cannot use ref local 'text' inside 
            //  an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression
            if (text.Length < 1 || text[0] != 'S') 
                return false;

            text = text.Slice(1);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you think `TryParseS` is compiled? The CLR does not really have nested functions; it's all a lie told by the compiler.

Comment: @JeroenMostert To be fair, you're not supposed to have to worry about that. If the compiler tells you that a feature cannot be used inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression, when you're not using that feature inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression, that sounds like a compiler bug to me. The error message should mention local functions.

Comment: @hvd: I was just about to change my comment to mention the diagnostic should probably be amended -- but now I won't. :-)

Comment: Amending the diagnostic would still leave me with 'why is this a restriction?'.

Comment: Because it won't work in general. You can produce a delegate from the local function. It's true that the compiler could allow this when it can show you're not using the function that way. It's a matter of debate if the added complexity and inconsistent semantics would be worth it. (It would probably necessitate a new error instead: "cannot convert local function to delegate since it's using ref locals".) You could open an issue for it if you think it's really a good idea to have this, rather than forcing you to be explicit about it.

Comment: Why the tag `system.memory` ?

Comment: @RandRandom It's a question related to the types and extension methods defined in the NuGet package `System.Memory`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler message is incomplete and should mention local functions as well.

> Amending the diagnostic would still leave me with 'why is this a restriction?'.

Local functions cannot reference ref-like structs from outer scope because local functions need not be called locally.

```
Action a;

void f() {
    var s = "Hello, world!\n".AsReadOnlySpan();
    void g() {
        foreach (var c in s)
            Console.Write(c);
    }
    a = g;
}

void h() {
    a(); //call a which is in fact the "local" method g in f
}
```

You mention:

> (Passing text as ref ReadOnlySpan works fine.)

This is correct, but this changes the method's signature. If the compiler were to do that, it would no longer be possible to pass the local function as a delegate type.

---

As mentioned in the comments:

A different translation of local functions is possible that would actually allow this, it would merely disallow such a local function from being assigned to `Action`:

```
Action a;

ref struct S {
    public ReadOnlySpan<char> s;
    public void g() {
        foreach (var c in s)
            Console.Write(c);
    }
}

void f() {
    S s;
    s.s = "Hello, world!\n".AsReadOnlySpan();
    s.g(); // okay
    a = s.g; // error
}
```

This might actually be a good idea to propose as a future extension to C#. At this time though, it hasn't been designed or implemented. There are several corner cases that would need to be considered before this could be allowed, such as when there are multiple local functions with some overlap in captures.

Comment: Extended your answer with an example of calling a, hope thats okay.

Comment: @RandRandom This sort of edit is generally better to suggest in a comment first, but if you had done that, yeah, I'd probably have added it.

Comment: Yes, I now see the shared parent local variables are allocate on the heap, not the stack like Pascal.

Comment: I'd say this has nothing to do with the fact that it *might* be assigned to a delegate. It is because `Span<T>` and friends are "stack-only" types and the way various features work in C# is that they generate hidden types with fields to capture any local state. The same restriction applies to async or iterator methods. They cannot have parameters or locals of type `Span<T>` (or `ReadOnlySpan<T>`).

Comment: @mikez The fact that it *might* be assigned to a delegate is what prevents the compiler from changing the signature. If the compiler were allowed to do that, it'd be possible to make it work, as jyoung noted in the question itself.

Comment: I guess I'm comparing this to what happens with a standard captured variable in a local function. Without a delegate assignment, the captured variable to local function is assigned to a value type field and passed as a by ref parameter. With a delegate assignment this is completely changed. It seems to me the compiler could do exactly what is needed to make it work if it did not assign to a field.

Comment: @mikez In fact, thinking about it, the compiler wouldn't even need to change the signature: the compiler-generated structure that holds all captured variables could be made a ref struct if any captured variables were refs or ref-like types. If the compiler did that, then the conversion to `Action` would be valid if and only if no refs or ref-like types were captured.