# System.Text.Json / NUnit - Unit testing custom Json converter / Utf8JsonReader

Tags: c#, nunit, system.text.json

I have a series of test methods to verify whether my custom Json converter (System.Text.Json) throws expected exceptions. One of such method:

```
[Test]
public void ReadJsonTokenNullThrows()
{
    // Arrange

    // Act & Assert
    var exception = Assert.Throws<JsonException>(() =>
    {
         var utf8JsonReader = new Utf8JsonReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("null"), false, new JsonReaderState(new JsonReaderOptions()));
         utf8JsonReader.Read();

         sut.Read(ref utf8JsonReader, typeof(DateTime), serializerOptions);
    });

    Assert.AreEqual("JSON value was a literal null", exception.Message);
}
```

I'd like to have only the line `sut.Read(...);` inside the `Assert.Throws..` code block, however when I move the Utf8JsonReader initialization and utf8JsonReader.Read() outside of it, I get the compiler error:

```
Cannot use ref local 'utf8JsonReader' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression.
```

Is there a way around to do this? Preferably without the try/catch

Comment: `Utf8JsonReader` is a ref-struct and hence it cannot be passed to the lambda method. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62019783/test-method-which-throws-an-exception-as-has-span-as-a-parameter.

Comment: Why do you want to move the var utf8JsonReader line outside of the code block?  For code cleanliness?

Comment: @DanCsharpster Mainly so that I could isolate the piece of code that is actually expected to throw the exception

Comment: Gotcha.  Basically it sounds like this is not easily doable.  I think this answer will expand on what @popsiporkkanaa was talking about.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654145/spant-can-not-be-a-nested-local-variable-why-is-this-a-restriction#49655144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utf8JsonReader is a ref-struct and hence it cannot be passed to the lambda method. See:

```
Assert.Throws<FormatException>(() =>
        {
            var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json), options);
            while (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.None)
            {
                if (!reader.Read())
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            _target.Read(ref reader, typeof(DateOnly), null);
        });
```

where _target is a custom DateOnlyConverter